# $(2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, maximal-and-prime-ideals

How does one show that $(2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_6$?

With it being modular arithmetic I’m not sure how this is done. I know I have to show that if $ab \in (2)$ then either $a \in (2)$ or $b\in (2)$.

Comment: How to do this without this knowledge?

Comment: @DonThousand Another argument is needed, since e.g. (5) is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$ab \in (2)$ implies that $ab \in \{0,2,4\}$. Now suppose $a,b \not\in \{0,2,4\}$, same as saying that $a,b \in \{1,3,5\}$.

Now you can check that $\{1,3,5\}$ is closed under multiplication . This shows that $ab \in \{1,3,5\}$, a contradiction.

**Another way:**

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_6/\langle 2 \rangle=\{0+\langle 2 \rangle,\, 1+\langle 2 \rangle,\, 3+\langle 2 \rangle,\, 5+\langle 2 \rangle\}$. Now show that this ring is an integral domain.

Comment: That helps, thanks.

Comment: 3 is not a unit in the ring!

Comment: It is a zero divisor!

Comment: Is there a foolproof method for a larger ring such as Z_15

Comment: @Group23 Yes, one should consider the quotient ring $R/I$ and see if this is an integral domain. What I did was to show that $R \setminus I$ is multiplicatively closed (another way to show that $I$ is a prime ideal).

Comment: I want to show $\mathbb{Z}_6 / (2) \cong [\mathbb{Z} / (6)] / [(2)/(6) ]$ so that by third isomorphism theorem it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / (2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @Group23 Are you familiar with the correspondence theorem?

Comment: To do that I need to show $2\mathbb{Z} \cong (2)/(6)$. How do I show that? Then I can make that first step and use the third isomorphism theorem

Comment: @Group23 $2\mathbb{Z} \not\cong \langle 2 \rangle/\langle 6 \rangle$.

Comment: I meant $(2) \cong (2)/(6) $

Comment: I.e how to show $(2) \cong 2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Group23 It is silly to wonder if $(2)\cong 2\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ because $(2)$ is **equal to** $2\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ in this ring.